# clearInterval does nothing

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

it is simple, setIntervall starts 't' normally and go is false, clearinterval does nothing and go is true. So if app.post get executed the third time, I have 2 Intervalls, processing t. I dont understand why.

```
go= true;
app.post('/s', function s(req, res){
    if (go){
        setInterval(t, 3000);
        go = false;
    }else{
        clearInterval(t);
        go = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: `var x = setInterval(...)` ... then `clearInterval(x);`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setInterval` returns an identifier that needs to be passed to `clearInterval` - you don't clear it by passing a function reference:

```
go= true;
var interval=0;
app.post('/s', function s(req, res){
    if (go){
        interval = setInterval(t, 3000);
        go = false;
    }else{
        clearInterval(interval);
        go = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: setInterval returns integer, so setting the variable to integer is better to avoid variable type convertation.

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze, Never thought it that way! **Thanks**

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze I'm unsure if the spec specifically says it _has_ to be an integer, just a unique handle.  It definitely _does_ say that `clearInterval` will ignore unknown inputs though, so it's safe for it to not be initialised.

Comment: @James Thorpe no your answer is right, its just a matter of performance, even though a little one, things stack up quickly

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze Indeed (which is why I didn't rollback the edit) - just saying that you shouldn't _rely_ on it being an integer (at least not without carefully inspecting the specfication)

Comment: Found it - it's guaranteed to be an int: _" let handle be a user-agent-defined integer that is greater than zero that will identify the timeout"_

Answer (score 2):

You have to set variable to setInterval like this:

```
go= true;
var interval = 0;
app.post('/s', function s(req, res){
 if (go){
    interval = setInterval(t, 3000);
    go = false;
}else{
    clearInterval(interval);
    go = true;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all; you have to assign the setInterval to a variable, as suggested by the other answers, and if it still does not work, continue to read below...

Ok, I have suffered this same problem too many time and usually I just let it be,
But most times I realize that after clearing interval the interval continues to run, and this might affect the performance of the device (it's like having an infinite loop).

So I did a little bit of research and I found out what the problem was and I wrote a simple code to solve it.

Now when you start an interval (most likely triggered by an event) in most cases, more than one instance of that interval is declared (for whatever reason)...

So when you clear the interval later, you only clear the *top-level interval, and the next level interval sets in.
(top-level might not be the correct word)

So to truly clear the interval I used the method below:

**Setting the interval:**

```
if(!timer)   
    timer =setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
```

**Clearing the interval:**

```
clearInterval(timer);
timer=null;
while (timer!== null){
    timer=null;
}
```

you might decide to clear the interval inside the while loop, but I found that this works for me and it's quite efficient than that.

> Make sure you check the scope of the interval variable (i.e timer in the case above)